# Java - что не то с кодом

Tags: java, intellij-idea

```
public class Coon {
String name = "Spiffo";
int mass = 8;
String profession = "survivor";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Coon sipffoObject = new Coon();
    System.out.println(spiffoObject.runaway(20));
}
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, intellij подчёркивает последнюю строку, ругаясь на spiffoObject, в чем причина?

Comment: Напишите текст ошибки в вопросе

Comment: так вы же пропустили последнюю закрывающую фигурную скобку `}`.

Comment: Нет, вообще мимо, я уточнил же, что ошибка где-то именно в spiffoObject.runaway - не могу понять, почему, - только начал изучать язык, это вопрос к азам логики

Comment: Может потому, что у вас отсутствует метод `runaway`?

Comment: У вас так и задумывалось `sipffoObject` и `spiffoObject`?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, ошибка синтаксиса, так как у вас не хватает закрывающей фигурной скобки "}".

**[UPDATE]:** Вторая синтаксическая ошибка, вы пишите `Coon sipffoObject = new Coon();`, а обращаетесь к `spiffoObject.runaway...`

Вот корректировка:

```
public class Coon {
    String name = "Spiffo";
    int mass = 8;
    String profession = "survivor";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Coon spiffoObject = new Coon();
        System.out.println(spiffoObject.runaway(20));
    }
}
```

Comment: Круто брать ответы с моего коммента.

Comment: @And это разрешено

Answer (score 0):

sipffoObject и spiffoObject, простая опечатка, благодарю всех, кто потратил время и проявил внимательность, мне премию Дарвина, пжлста)

Answer (score -1):

Посмотрите внимательно на ваш код:

```
Coon sipffoObject = new Coon();
System.out.println(spiffoObject.runaway(20));
```

sipffoObject и spiffoObject - внимательно смотрите(по буквам сравнивайте) что написали:)